# sklearn CountVectorizer output a matrix with empty rows

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am using CountVectorizer to generate vector for each document. In my case, a document is a short text consists of 1-5 words.

```
for i, doc in enumerate(documents):
    if doc: # make sure there is no empty document.
        corpus.append(doc)

countVectorizer = CountVectorizer()
weight_arr = countVectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

for doc_index, count_vector in enumerate(weight_arr):
    nonzero_feature_indice = count_vector.nonzero()[1] # [1]: unique column index
    if nonzero_feature_indice.size == 0:
        print "EMPTY ROW!"
```

I use the default parameters of CountVectorizer. I do not remove stopwords and set any threshold which may generate empty documents.

```
{'binary': False, 'lowercase': True, 'stop_words': None, 'decode_error': u'strict', 'vocabulary': None, 'tokenizer': None, 'encoding': u'utf-8', 'dtype': <type 'numpy.int64'>, 'analyzer': u'word', 'ngram_range': (1, 1), 'max_df': 1.0, 'min_df': 1, 'max_features': None, 'input': u'content', 'strip_accents': None, 'token_pattern': u'(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b', 'preprocessor': None}
```

I find that a few rows in the weight_arr are all-zero. Why is this possible?

Comment: Is it possible that you have documents with only one-letter words ? The tokenizer filters these out.

Comment: @user3914041 Yes. I think it is possible. Do you know how to disable one-letter removal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your setup, documents with one-letter words only will give all-zero arrays. 
One-letter words are being filtered out by your `tokenizer`.

You did not specify any, but the default uses the following token pattern:

```
'token_pattern': u'(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b'
```

If you want to allow one-letter words you can change it to:

```
'token_pattern': u'(?u)\\b\\w+\\b'
```

You just need to pass it to the constructor:

```
countVectorizer = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=u'(?u)\\b\\w+\\b')
```

and it should work.